# Let $f_n(t)= \sin(nt)$. Prove that $f_n \rightharpoonup* 0 $ in $L^{\infty}[0,2\pi]$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, weak-convergence

I am strugling with this exercise:

> **Let $f_n(t)= \sin(nt)$. Prove that $f_n \rightharpoonup*  0 $ in $L^{\infty}[0,2\pi]$**
>
> **The solution given to me reads:**
>
> Since the given space is the dual of $L^1[0,2\pi] :$
> $L^{\infty}[0,2\pi] = (L^1[0,2\pi])'$
>
> Thinking of the $f_n(t)$ as linear functionals with domain in
> $L^1[0,2\pi]$
>
> Prove that $f_n(g)=\int_0^{2\pi}g(t)f_n(t)dt\to 0$ for all $g \in  L^1[0,2\pi]$
>
> It is enough to prove it holds  for $g$ in a set whose span is  dense in
> $L^1[0,2\pi]$ , like the $\Delta =\{1_{[a,b]}:  [a,b] \subset [0,2\pi]\}$.

That is straightforward since I can easily integrate $\sin(nt)$ over $[a,b] $and notice it converges to $0$, but I don't understand why/ I am not convinced that  it is enough to do so. I have read elsewhere that   " a sequence of continuous functions on a metric space that converges pointwise on a dense subset need not converge pointwise on the full space.",

**So why does it work in this particular case? Can you prove it?**

I have the following proven propositions, but none of them are exactly what I need, since this problem deals with weak * convergence instead

**Proposition 1**: $X$: Banach space, $E \subset X$, such that $\overline{(Span E)}=X$. Let $\{g_n\}\subset X'$, bounded such that $\exists \lim_{n \to \infty} g_n(x)$ $\forall x \in E$ Then $\exists g \in X' $such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} g_n(x)=g(x)$ $\forall x \in X$

which was actually used to prove:

**Proposition 2**: $X$: Banach space, $x_n \rightharpoonup x$ iff $\{x_n\}$ is bounded and $ \lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n)=f(x)$ $\forall f \in \Delta \subset X'$ 'such that $\overline{(Span \Delta)}=X'$

Answer (score 2):

The convergence

$$\int g(t)\sin(nt) dt \rightarrow 0$$

for $g$ integrable is known as the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma. There are many proofs of this lemma. I suggest that you look at these proofs, some indeed proceed by density.

Comment: does it has to be exactly with sinx? or any continuous function instead? Can't the problem be solved using one of the propositions above? The lecturer said we are doing so, but I Think it is an indirect thing

Comment: if you take instead of sine the constant function equal to 1, then the integral is always equal to the integral of $f$ and there is no reason that it is equal to 0.

Comment: All the proofs I can find are for the complex exponential instead and for a continuous limit and they all use the Fourier transform, which I don't know what has to do with functional analysis. Do you know of somewhere where it is done for sin(nt)?

Comment: If a sequence of complex numbers converges to zero, so does its imaginary part. Or just replace the complex exponential by the sine, and it will work. Moreover, the proof given on wikipedia does not use the Fourier transform.